# find the missmatch between names columns

Tags: r, names, rbind

I have multiple datasets (each has 123 variable). I was using rbind to merge the data. oddly enough names in one dataset does not match the rest. Using colnames I have both the column names in the problematic dataset and the rest. I cannot find the missmatch. Is there a way to ask r to find where the missmatch is exactly?
the following code shows there is a missmatch, but I need to pinpoint where...

```
identical(colnames(total4), colnames(dataset1))
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use setdiff.

```
setdiff(colnames(total4), colnames(dataset1))
```

Comment: Also this one worked: which(colnames(total4) != colnames(dataset1))

Comment: Indeed. That gives the index of the mismatch, which is useful if you want to do something with the mismatch afterward.